# CSV parsing not respecting enclosure

Tags: php, csv

I'm using `str_getcsv` to parse some text that comes down from the web server.

`<table class='DeploymentSummary'><tr><td>Program Name: Some Program</td></tr><tr><td>Time Zone:      &emsp;&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td>Industry Type:&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td>VAR Sheet Attached:&emsp;No</td></tr></table><tr><td>Notes: </td></ tr></table>,"<table class='DeploymentSummary'><tr><td>NAME, NAME - Some University - Food Zone</td></tr><tr><td></td></             tr><tr><td>123 N College Street, </td></tr><tr><td>New York, NY 36832</td></tr><tr><td>(222) 222-3333</td></tr></table>",,,335,Welcome  Letter,11,no,21722,,90,,NAME - Some University - Food Zone,NAME,,FedEx: Ground,,7,9441,1`

More readable format of CSV where each column is on its own row:

```
<table class='DeploymentSummary'><tr><td>Program Name: Some Program</td></tr><tr><td>Time Zone:      &emsp;&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td>Industry Type:&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td>VAR Sheet Attached:&emsp;No</td></tr></table><tr><td>Notes: </td></ tr></table>,
"<table class='DeploymentSummary'><tr><td>NAME, NAME - Some University - Food Zone</td></tr><tr><td></td></             tr><tr><td>123 N College Street, </td></tr><tr><td>New York, NY 36832</td></tr><tr><td>(222) 222-3333</td></tr></table>",
,
,
335,
Welcome  Letter,
11,
no,
21722,
,
90,
,
NAME - Some University - Food Zone,
NAME,
,
FedEx: Ground,
,
7,
9441,
1
```

I'm parsing it into an array with `$rec = str_getcsv($record);` where `$record` is the CSV text pasted above. Encoding that array as JSON for readability, it produces

```
    [
  "<table class='DeploymentSummary'><tr><td>Program Name: Some Program<\/td><\/               tr><tr><td>Time Zone:&emsp;&emsp;<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Industry Type:&emsp;<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>VAR Sheet Attached:&emsp;No<\/td><\/tr><\/ table><tr><td>Notes: <\/td><\/tr><\/table>",
  null,
  "",
  "",
  "335",
  "Welcome Letter",
  "11",
  "no",
  "21722",
  "",
  "90",
  "",
  "NAME - Some              University - Food Zone",
  "NAME",
  "",
  "FedEx: Ground",
  "",
  "7",
  "9441",
  "1"
]
```

The issue is the second column of the CSV. It displays as `null` in the parsed array. It contains commas, but is enclosed with `"`. 
The PHP docs state that the default enclosure character is `"`. I've also explicitly set the enclosure character to `"` but that didn't help either.

Comment: Can you please format the code and csv to make it readable?

Comment: Using str_getcsv() to try and parse html markup isn't ever likely to be successful.... use the right functions for the right task, and they work..... the wrong tools generally won't work.... to parse html markup, use something like DomDocument, and use str_getcsv() for csv data instead

Comment: @MarkBaker What would the right tools be for this then? I'm not a PHP guru and just tasked with these things at work, so I just try to figure it out as I go

Comment: html is not csv, and you'll NEVER be able to parse it as csv. "This is an apple, I'm going to treat it like a ferrari - why did it turn into mush when I tried to drive it?". Use a DOM parser

Comment: No, but it's text embedded between quotes in comma separated form. It has been working exactly like this for the past month and just happened to break on this string. I'm constrained to using CSV because this is how the web service sends it down, and that's out of my control

Comment: I cannot reproduce: http://3v4l.org/u0SOJ

Comment: @bishop thanks for trying. Maybe it's an issue somewhere else. Thanks for this tool though, I'll be using it plenty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having this same issue come up several times in the pass week, I figured out the issue. Inside the quoted string that is coming back `null` when parsing it, is a hidden unicode character that I was mistaking as a space.

Upon inspecting the logs I found `<td>General Stores <96> V</td>` where `<96>` is a unicode character for [`START OF GUARDED AREA`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/96/index.htm).

Editing the field in the backend that's serving this data by replacing what looks like a space with a real space fixed the issue.